# Trying to INSERT data into SQLite but getting empty response

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I am able to query the DB and get info back but when I try to insert a row in an SQLite DB , I get an empty response.

My query that returns something:

```
const response = await sql('SELECT * FROM work_orders ORDER BY CASE WHEN status = "OPEN" THEN 1 WHEN status = "CLOSED" THEN 2 ELSE 3 END')
```

and the insertion that won't work:

```
const response = await sql('INSERT INTO work_orders (name, status) VALUES (?, "OPEN")', workOrderName);
return res.status(201).json({ response });
```

What could I be missing?

the table was created with `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`

Comment: what is the NAME field of the table? if you type `.schema <table>` you will get the definition. Also which sql library are you using with node?

Comment: the NAME field = `'name' varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont really know SQLite but maybe if you try RETURNING *, it may work.

```
const response = await sql('INSERT INTO work_orders (name, status) VALUES (?, "OPEN") RETURNING *', workOrderName);
return res.status(201).json({ response });
```